# How to set Inquire Access Code (IAC) via AT commands on HC-05?

Tags: arduino-uno, hc-05

I am trying to set IAC of HC05 via AT Commands, but for some reason, the result is not as desired.

I need to set the IAC as '1234', for which I enter the command:

```
AT+IAC=1234
```

The module responds OK, but when I ask `AT+IAC?`, it replies '01234'.

Now, it has been troubling me for the past few days. I've also tried adding '\r\n' to the end of command, but it sets the IAC as '1234444'

I would be thankful if you could help me with this! I tried searching the net but to no avail.

Comment: Are you manually talking to the HC-05 via a direct serial connection or via an Arduino program?

Comment: I do it via the serial monitor of the Arduino IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have `\r\n` in both the set and read command.

Example:

```
AT+IAC=12345f\r\n
OK

AT+IAC?\r\n
+IAC: 12345f
OK
```

Comment: Thanks MatsK, but I'm afraid it doesn't work. When I enter the code AT+IAC?\r\n , it gives Error(0) which I've looked is for command error. Trying it without \r\n in the inquiry code resulted in +IAC:12344444. Any idea what's cooking up there?